# DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea dosen't work

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, aero-glass

i am very new to WTL
here is code of onCreate of my main dialog

```
int Cwin32_mfcDlg::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDialogEx::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    // TODO:  Add your specialized creation code here
    MARGINS mar = {0};
    mar.cyBottomHeight = 100;
    DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(m_hWnd,&mar);
    return 0;
}
```

but when i try to compile my project i get this error

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea@8 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall Cwin32_mfcDlg::OnCreate(struct tagCREATESTRUCTA *)" (?OnCreate@Cwin32_mfcDlg@@QAEHPAUtagCREATESTRUCTA@@@Z)
```

and here is output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: win32_mfc, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 5/24/2012 1:08:43 AM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\win32_mfc.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  win32_mfcDlg.cpp
1>ResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>win32_mfcDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea@8 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall Cwin32_mfcDlg::OnCreate(struct tagCREATESTRUCTA *)" (?OnCreate@Cwin32_mfcDlg@@QAEHPAUtagCREATESTRUCTA@@@Z)
1>D:\projects\C++\Projects\Team_projects\Bill\net\ttt\win32_mfc\Debug\win32_mfc.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.48
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

and this is my StdAfx.h code:

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently,
// but are changed infrequently

#pragma once

#ifndef _SECURE_ATL
#define _SECURE_ATL 1
#endif

#ifndef VC_EXTRALEAN
#define VC_EXTRALEAN            // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
#endif

#include "targetver.h"

#define _ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS      // some CString constructors will be explicit

// turns off MFC's hiding of some common and often safely ignored warning messages
#define _AFX_ALL_WARNINGS

#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions


#include <afxdisp.h>        // MFC Automation classes



#ifndef _AFX_NO_OLE_SUPPORT
#include <afxdtctl.h>           // MFC support for Internet Explorer 4 Common Controls
#endif
#ifndef _AFX_NO_AFXCMN_SUPPORT
#include <afxcmn.h>             // MFC support for Windows Common Controls
#endif // _AFX_NO_AFXCMN_SUPPORT

#include <afxcontrolbars.h>     // MFC support for ribbons and control bars


#include <dwmapi.h>     // DWM APIs



//#ifdef _UNICODE
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_IA64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='ia64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
//#endif
```

this project is in MFC and Visual Studio 2010 and in Windows 7 x64

Comment: What's in targetver.h? Needs to define Vista or up. 0x0600. No, I'm talking nonsense. Linker error, as per answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [`DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you need to link with `Dwmapi.lib`.

Comment: You need to add it the list of `.lib`s that you link with. Unfortunately, I can't help navigate the VS2010 IDE as I don't use IDEs, sorry.

Comment: This might help: http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/help/settings_vc10.html